# What does Rsync's output tell here about to-chk?

Tags: rsync

I was using rsync using --progress option , So the file transfer completed and I got following output

```
receiving incremental file list
Makefile
          9,935 100%    9.47MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
```

My question is what does `to-chk=0/1` means ?

I am transferring only 1 file here ,that is Makefile.
transfer number (xfr#1) clearly indicates 1 file , but what does to-chk = 0/1 stands for ?

Comment: Did your transfer only consist of one file?

Comment: yes , only 1 file

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`to-chk` or `to-check` gives you the number of files still to be checked, e.g. `0/1` means 0 of a total of 1 files in the queue still need to be checked.

During a normal transfer with, let's say 42 files, `to-check` will basically count down from 42 to 0 (`to-check=38/42`…`to-check=2/42`) until `rsync` is done syncing.

Note that for large amounts of files, the last number in `to-check` may also grow since `rsync` doesn't queue all files at once (`to-check=38/42`...`to-check=2/56`). That's because it uses [a recursion algorithm](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html):

> Beginning with rsync 3.0.0, the recursive algorithm used is now an incremental scan that uses much less memory than before and begins the transfer after the scanning of the first few directories have been completed.

To disable this behavior add the `--no-inc-recursive` option.

Note that in newer releases of rsync (3.1.0), the label has been changed to `ir-chk` to indicate incremental recursive progress (ie: the default) and `to-check` to indicate non incremental recursive progress (ie: with the `--no-inc-recursive` option).

Comment: I think in addition to this, ir-chk is when it is still scanning through the filesystem and there are more of the filesystem to scan through, then when it reaches the end, it changes to say to-chk, meaning no more scanning is required and the total value output is the final countdown, it wont increment anymore